# Formula (not an algorithm, i.e. defining a function) for the nearest number of the form n(n+1), where n is an integer

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What would be the formula which defines a function that returns the nearest number of the form *n*(*n*+1), where *n* is an integer?

Comment: How do you distinguish a formula from an algorithm?  Both are supposed to take an input and provide an output.

Comment: Algorithms need not be a concrete implementation of a procedure. He just wants the juice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a positive real number $x$, you are really just solving 
$$
x= n(n+1)
$$
which has solution
$$
n=\dfrac{\sqrt{4x+1}-1}{2}
$$
Then the function you want (almost) is
$$
n(x)= \dfrac{\sqrt{4x+1}-1}{2}
$$
Of course, this need not be an exact integer, but will be the real number closest to the actual integer $n$. So simply round to the nearest integer and this will be your $n$. Then you can simply compose with the function $g(n)= n(n+1)$ and then this will be the integer closest to $x$ with the integer being of the form $n(n+1)$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If the input is $k$, let's imagine there is an integer $n$ such that $n(n+1)=k$.  This is equivalent to $n^2+n-k=0$, which is a nice quadratic with solution $n=\frac 12(-1+\sqrt{1+4k})$ where we took the plus sign because we want $n$ to be positive.  If the calculated $n$ is not an integer, try the one above and the one below, find the closest, and you are done.